# Send Message to users inbox using PHP based facebook apps

Tags: php, facebook

I have created an application which can post to users wall or even send emails to selected users, what I have not been able to come up with is the functionality to let an application send a message to users facebook inbox, I have googled it and found that applications are not allowed to send messages to users inbox however there's this product called rockmelt browser which does the same thing.

There's has to be some way which allows sending messages to users inbox.

Can somebody guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot send a message to a user's inbox. The closest thing may be this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/livemessage.send/. It allows you to send a live message to a particular user's browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the message from your application user to one of their Facebook friends, you can use a [Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/), which will show up in the notification area. When the user clicks on the notification, they'll be taken to your App Canvas where you can show them the full message and any other app interactions you want.